# F# list group by running total?

Tags: f#

I have the following list of tuples ordered by the first item. I want to cluster the times by

1. If the second item of the tuple is greater then 50, it will be in its own cluster.
2. Otherwise, cluster the items whose sum is less than 50.
3. The order cannot be changed.

code:

```
let values =
  [("ACE", 78);
   ("AMR", 3);
   ("Aam", 6);
   ("Acc", 1);
   ("Adj", 23);
   ("Aga", 12);
   ("All", 2);
   ("Ame", 4); 
   ("Amo", 60);
   //.... 
  ]
values |> Seq.groupBy(fun (k,v) -> ???)
```

The expected value will be

```
[["ACE"] // 78
 ["AMR"; "Aam"; "Acc"; "Adj"; "Aga"; "All"] // 47
 ["Ame"] // 4
 ["Amo"] // 60
....]
```

Ideally, I want to evenly distribute the second group (`["AMR"; "Aam"; "Acc"; "Adj"; "Aga"; "All"]` which got the sum of 47) and the third one (`["Ame"]` which has only 4).

How to implement it in F#?

---

I had the following solution. It uses a mutable variable. It's not F# idiomatic? Is `for ... do` imperative in F# or is it a syntactic sugar of some function construct?

```
seq {
    let mutable c = []
    for v in values |> Seq.sortBy(fun (k, _) -> k) do
        let sum = c |> Seq.map(fun (_, v) -> v) |> Seq.sum
        if not(c = []) && sum + (snd v) > 50 
        then 
            yield c
            c <- [v]
        else
            c <- List.append c [v]
 }
```

Comment: When you say you want to "evenly distribute" the second group, could you give an example of what you mean? Because I can see two things you *might* mean by it: 1) You want the number of *strings* to be more or less even (e.g., `["AMR'; "Aam"; "Acc"]` in group one and `["Adj"; "Aga"; "All"; "Ame"]` in group two because that's a 3-4 distribution). Or 2) you want the *total values* between groups one and two to be as close as possible (which would put `["AMR'; "Aam"; "Acc"; "Adj"]` in group one, total 33, and `["Aga"; "All"; "Ame"]` in group two, total 18). Which one of those do you want?

Comment: BTW, just because something uses a mutable variable internally while you're building the result does not make it un-idiomatic F#. The important thing is that you don't mutate any data that *other functions can see*. Using a mutable variable to build up an immutable result is a very common pattern in F#.

Comment: The (2) is what I want. I want the _value_ to be more evenly distributed.

Comment: To answer what you just asked in your edit: `for ... do` in F# can be either imperative or syntactic sugar. It's imperative when it appears in normal code, but when it appears in a computation expression (like `seq { ... }`) then it's syntactic sugar for a functional construct. BTW, you wrote `seq [ ... ]` but that should really be `seq { ... }`. By writing `seq [ ... ]` you're building a list and then converting it to a seq, which is inefficient.

Comment: Updated `seq []` to `seq {}`. In Haskell, it also has some imperative like statement and they are just syntactic sugar of its pure functional constructs. I'm wondering why I cannot use `yield` in `Seq.iter()` instead of `for .... do`.

Comment: You can't use `yield` in `Seq.iter()` because `Seq.iter()` isn't a computation expression. You can't use `yield` inside `for ... do` either, *unless* the `for ... do` is inside a computation expression (in which case it's similar to Haskell's imperative-like statements: it's merely syntactic sugar for functional constructs). Computation expressions change the meaning of `for ... do`, and allow `yield`. Note that you can't use `yield` in a `Seq.map()` either (which is far closer to what you meant, I think, than `Seq.iter()`). To return a value in `Seq.map()`, you just return it normally.

Comment: I think you need to `yield c` as the last statement in `seq {... yield c }`

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it. Not the nicest code ever, but works and is immutable.

```
let foldFn (acc:(string list * int) list) (name, value) =
    let addToLast last = 
        let withoutLast = acc |> List.filter ((<>) last)
        let newLast = [((fst last) @ [name]), (snd last) + value]
        newLast |> List.append withoutLast

    match acc |> List.tryLast with
    | None -> [[name],value]
    | Some l ->
        if (snd l) + value <= 50 then addToLast l
        else [[name], value] |> List.append acc

values |> List.fold foldFn [] |> List.map fst
```

**Update**: Since append can be quite expensive operation, I added prepend only version (still fulfills original requirement to keep order).

```
let foldFn (acc:(string list * int) list) (name, value) =
    let addToLast last = 
        let withoutLast = acc |> List.filter ((<>) last) |> List.rev
        let newLast = ((fst last) @ [name]), (snd last) + value
        (newLast :: withoutLast) |> List.rev

    match acc |> List.tryLast with
    | None -> [[name],value]
    | Some l ->
        if (snd l) + value <= 50 then addToLast l
        else ([name], value) :: (List.rev acc) |> List.rev
```

Note: *There is still `@` operator on line 4 (when creating new list of names in cluster), but since the theoretical maximum amount of names in cluster is 50 (if all of them would be equal 1), the performance here is negligible.*

If you remove `List.map fst` on last line, you would get sum value for each cluster in list.

Comment: Just wondering if `let withoutLast = acc |> List.filter ((<>) last)` will make a new copy of the list excluding the last element and it can be expensive.

Comment: I actually don't care about the order inside each cluster. I think it can insert the new item in the head to avoid `List.filter`.

Comment: It is meant to be immutable so basically any operation on list creates new one. But the `append` can be expensive (I did not care in original solution). I'll update it with prepend only version.

Answer (score 2):

Append operations are expensive. A straight-forward fold with prepended intermediate results is cheaper, even if the lists need to be reversed after processing.

```
["ACE", 78; "AMR", 3; "Aam", 6; "Acc", 1; "Adj", 23; "Aga", 12; "All", 2; "Ame", 4; "Amd", 6; "Amo", 60]
|> List.fold (fun (r, s1, s2) (t1, t2) ->
    if t2 > 50 then [t1]::s1::r, [], 0
    elif s2 + t2 > 50 then s1::r, [t1], t2
    else r, t1::s1, s2 + t2 ) ([], [], 0)
|> fun (r, s1, _) -> s1::r
|> List.filter (not << List.isEmpty)
|> List.map List.rev
|> List.rev
// val it : string list list =
//   [["ACE"]; ["AMR"; "Aam"; "Acc"; "Adj"; "Aga"; "All"]; ["Ame"; "Amd"];
//    ["Amo"]]
```

Comment: I changed the input to `let values =
  [("ACE", 78);
   ("AMR", 3);
   ("Aam", 6);
   ("Acc", 1);
   ("Adj", 23);
   ("Aga", 12);
   ("All", 2);
   ("Ame", 4); ("Amd", 6);
   ("Amo", 60);
   //.... 
  ];;` and the result is not right. The "Ame" and "Amd" should be in the same set.

Comment: I added a new item "Amd" with a value of 6 and tested the code.

Comment: @ca9163d9 You are right. The case of a single tuple exceeding the threshold should be handled differently from the sums doing the same. Two tests are required; one prepending immediately, the other starting a new aggregate.

Comment: @kaefer: I think you're missing to sort the list before folding

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive version - working much the same way as fold-versions:

```
let groupBySums data =
    let rec group cur sum acc lst =
        match lst with
        | [] -> acc |> List.where (not << List.isEmpty) |> List.rev
        | (name, value)::tail when value > 50 -> group [] 0 ([(name, value)]::(cur |> List.rev)::acc) tail
        | (name, value)::tail -> 
            match sum + value with
            | x when x > 50 -> group [(name, value)] 0 ((cur |> List.rev)::acc) tail
            | _ -> group ((name, value)::cur) (sum + value) acc tail
    (data |> List.sortBy (fun (name, _) -> name)) |> group [] 0 []

values |> groupBySums |> List.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution using `Seq.mapFold` and `Seq.groupBy`:

```
let group values =
    values
    |> Seq.mapFold (fun (group, total) (name, count) -> 
        let newTotal = count + total
        let newGroup = group + if newTotal > 50 then 1 else 0
        (newGroup, name), (newGroup, if newGroup = group then newTotal else count) 
        ) (0, 0)
    |> fst
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.map    (snd >> Seq.map snd >> Seq.toList)
```

Invoke it like this:

```
[   "ACE", 78
    "AMR", 3
    "Aam", 6
    "Acc", 1
    "Adj", 23
    "Aga", 12
    "All", 2
    "Ame", 4
    "Amo", 60
] 
|> group        
|> Seq.iter    (printfn "%A")

// ["ACE"]
// ["AMR"; "Aam"; "Acc"; "Adj"; "Aga"; "All"]
// ["Ame"]
// ["Amo"]
```